# How can i solve a first order deferential using python that has another function in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, double, sympy, symbolic-integration

My problem is sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997954/substitute-the-derivative-of-a-function-in-a-symbolic-expression)
and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038324/python-ode-first-order-how-to-solve-this-using-sympy%20) combined but not quite. Anyway what im trying to do is take a double integral of a function using sympy to get the symbolic answer. The problem is that inside the derivative element and the integrals thereare 2 other functions and im not sure how to show that they are functions and not just constants. Here is what i have so far.

```
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

x=sp.Symbol('x') #a and k are constants
z=sp.Symbol('z')
k=sp.Symbol('k')
f=sp.Function('f')(x)
l=sp.Function('l')(x)

def dN(x,z):
    return -N*f*z**(a-2)

def b(x,z):
    return l*x*dN

def c(x,z):
    return z*l*x*dN

res=integrate(b,(z,k,float('inf')),(x,0,float('inf')))
sp.pprint (res)              
#print(b)
```

This is what im using for dN:

[image]

This is the integral im trying to preform to get eqn 12:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there might be some confusion between sympy functions and python functions. When you define `b(x, z)` that is a python function. When you refer to `b` in your integrate line you should supply the variables that are needed for the function, hence `integrate(b(x, z)...)`. The same applies for `dN` that is called in functions `b` and `c` without args. (It should be `...*dN(x, z)`. In the dN function you define, you refer to `N` but don't define it. I would recommend that at the top you define `N = sp.Function('N')(x, z)`. Finally, you can use `sp.oo` to refer to infinity rather than creating a floating point representation of the same.

Sorry I can't test it here. Hopefully these suggestions will help you get on track! :-)

Comment: I did that for all the functions including l, but it says l(x) is not callable. As the pic shows the function in terms of x will not be integrated. Should i just try to do the whole thing in terms of z only?

Comment: I think you should be using the ode module as I demonstrate [here](https://repl.it/JQr3) but it only works in 1D.

Comment: is it supposed to take this long to run?

Comment: How long did it take?